# Array not responding to forEach

Tags: javascript

Here's some test in my Chrome dev console:

```
> tags
returns ["test_tag", "test_tag2"]

> tags.forEach
returns undefined

> ["test_tag", "test_tag2"].forEach
returns forEach() { [native code] }
```

I have no idea why my `tags` object is not responding to `forEach`.

Checking the type is not very instructive, which is to be expected:

```
> typeof(tags)
// returns 'object'
> typeof(["test_tag", "test_tag2"])
// returns 'object'
```

How am I constructing this `tags` object?

```
var $nodes = $(".metadata")
var tags = $nodes.map(function(idx, node){
  nodeJson = $(node).text()
  return JSON.parse(nodeJson)['tags']
})
```

Comment: can you show the actual code that assigns a value to `tags`? It is entirely unclear what that `tags` is on your first line. Just because it looks like an array when serialized to string does not mean it *is* an array: it could just as easily be a function's `arguments` content, which is array-like but does not have an array prototype, but may serialize in the same way an array does.

Comment: Try `console.assert(Object.prototype.toString.call(tags) == '[object Array]')`

Comment: `Array.isArray(tags)` ... jQuery's `.map` (looks like jQuery) might actually return a jQuery object?

Comment: So yeah, it's evidently not an array, as `Array.isArray` confirms. Still not clear on how I'm supposed to iterate through it, whatever it is though. I showed how it's defined at the end of my question, though. Would more information be helpful?

Comment: To iterate, use jQuery's `each` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `map()` function returns the collection of elements, or in this case the returned text wrapped in a jQuery object, which is of course an object, not an array.

If you wanted the text in an array, you'd use `get()` as well

```
var $nodes = $(".metadata")
var tags = $nodes.map(function(idx, node){
    var nodeJson = $(node).text();
    return JSON.parse(nodeJson)['tags'];
}).get();
```

or the more appropriate `$.map`

```
var $nodes = $(".metadata")
var tags = $.map( $nodes, function(node){
    var nodeJson = $(node).text();
    return JSON.parse(nodeJson)['tags'];
});
```

Comment: Cool yeah you got it. Using the different syntax for `map` fixed it. This experience did leave me wishing there was a `.class` method in Javascript though. `tags.constructor.name` returns the cryptically named `r`, which I've deduces is the "class" of a jquery selection.

Comment: Unfortuntaly there isn't, but an easy *(in no way reliable in production)* way to check if something is a jQuery object, is to just do `"prevObject" in tags`, as all jQuery objects do have a `prevObject` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(tags, function(el){
    console.log(el);
});
```